# I need an equalizer for my live audio stream

Tags: flash, apache-flex, stream, jwplayer, rtmp

I have tried to use jwplayer and flowplayer, for jwplayer I have found some equalizers but they don't work for live audio streams, I need to have a "monitor" for my live stream, so I tought I could use a equalizer (if there is sound, the bars will be moving, if there isn't any sound, the bars will be static...).

I want to have a page with my rtmp stream playing and an equalizer to know if the stream is having sound or not... Should I create my own player? if yes, please point me in the right direction...

If there are any already created players that support this feature, pelase let me know!

Thanks in advance!

If this isn't possible, at least tell me what should I do.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example of where you tried to do this with the JW Player?